# Samba server not visible from Win network

Tags: iptables, samba, server-message-block, smb-conf

Samba 3.5 on Centos 6.3

Synopsis: I set up Samba on my linux host, but none of my Win machines on the subnet can see the host name.

---

My host name (WOLTEST) does not show up in any of the Win network lists (net view, for example). So, \\WOLTEST\share-name comes back empty-handed

I can ping the Linux ip address (192.168.44.140) from the Win machines, but I cannot get to the share with \\192.168.44.140\share-name.

There are a few similar posts on ServerFault, but none helped.

Here's the relevant parts of my smb.conf:

```
[global]
workgroup = LANGROUP
server string = Samba Server Version %v

security = user
passdb backend = tdbsam

[web]
path = /volume1/web
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
valid users = michael
guest ok = yes
```

I also tried "wins support = yes", but it didn't help. There are no wins servers on the LAN.

---

I ran smbpasswd -a michael

Then I restarted smb & nmb.

Here are the relevant lines from /var/log/messages

```
[2012/07/30 16:17:05.161348,  0] smbd/server.c:501(smbd_open_one_socket)
 smbd_open_once_socket: open_socket_in: Address already in use
[2012/07/30 16:17:05.166246,  0] smbd/server.c:501(smbd_open_one_socket)
 smbd_open_once_socket: open_socket_in: Address already in use
[2012/07/30 16:17:38.237999,  0] nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:395(become_local_master_stage2)
*****

Samba name server WOLTEST is now a local master browser for
                 workgroup LANGROUP on subnet 192.168.44.140
```

I've googled the phrase "Address already in use", and everyone says to ignore it.

The one red flag for me is the phrase "on subnet 192.168.44.140". That IP is not a subnet. It's the IP of the host.

I don't know of any way to change that to subnet 192.168.44.0. But it's not the elected browser, anyway, so I'm not sure it would matter.

---

SELinux is off

I've searched everywhere and read the samba doc, and I seem to be doing everything right.

Is there something I've missed?

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've covered my usual suspects, but there is one word I didn't see in there and that's `iptables`. Could it be as easy as not having opened the right holes in the on-by-default firewall? I have had that whack me a time or three.

Comment: That was it! Just to test, I stopped the iptables service, and waited a while. I could then access the share. So now I need to come up with some specific rules.

Comment: I found these rules via google, and I tested them.

-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT

Comment: When in doubt, follow the money....or in this case, the packet.  Firewalling causes all kinds of headaches simply because it's usually forgotten about.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `system-config-firewall`, a simple gui that can make these choice for you, anyway these rules should work:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp  -m multiport  --dports 445,139  -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp  -m multiport  --dports 138,137,139  -m state --state NEW  -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you, it's good to have those rules. But system-config-firewall is no longer available for CentOS 6.3.

Comment: I find it in this official repository: http://centos.arcticnetwork.ca/6.3/os/i386/Packages/ for i386 and for x86_64.
There are 3 files: system-config-firewall-1.2.27-5.el6.noarch.rpm, 
system-config-firewall-base-1.2.27-5.el6.noarch.rpm and system-config-firewall-tui-1.2.27-5.el6.noarch.rpm, the tui version is shell only.